# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting For Dates and a Blank Row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets I am trying to use conditional formatting to change the format of a column of cells if the date in that column it more that 14 days before today, AND if a separate column is blank.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

Fore the specific range I want: `C2:C287`

Custom Formula:

```
=TODAY()-14 =AND =ISBLANK(L2:L287)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With C2:C287 selected, try this as the custom CF formula:

`=AND(C2<TODAY()-14,ISBLANK(L2))`

Conditional formatting rules only need the *first* cell in the range (and any relative ranges) in order to extrapolate the relationship to every other cell in the range.